# how to edit data in django?

Tags: python, django

I have retrieved data from the database and displayed it in a table. Now click of EDIT button I want to edit the form.i have sucessfully insert and retrived data from the database but i cant understand how to edit and save into database.

viwes.py

```
 def pramod(request):
     p1 = request.POST.get('name',' ')
     p2 = request.POST.get('address',' ')
     p3 = request.POST.get('city',' ')
     p4 = request.POST.get('sp',' ')
     p5 = request.POST.get('country',' ')
     p6 = request.POST.getlist('chk1[]',' ')
     p7 = request.POST.get('sex',' ')
     books =  Publisher(name=p1,address=p2,city=p3,state_province=p4,country=p5,course=p6,Gender=p7)
     books.save()
     dataset=Publisher.objects.all()
     data={
    'dataset':dataset,
     }

     return render(request,'Publisher.html',data)
```

models.py

```
  class Publisher(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        course = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        Gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Publisher.html

```
  <div class="col-lg-4"  style="margin-top: 100px">
    <form action="/pramod/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"  />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control"  />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>city</label>
                        <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>state_province</label>
                        <input type="text" name="sp" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>country</label>
                        <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Course</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]"  value="Dot.NET"  > Dot.NET
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]"  value="Python"  > Python
                     <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]"  value="Django"  > Django
                     </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Sex</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <input type="radio" name="sex" checked="checked" value="Male" >Male
                   <input type="radio" name="sex" checked="checked" value="Female" >Female
                    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-block">save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8" style="margin-top: 100px">
   <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered ">

    <B class="btn-success">Data</B> <thead class="btn-primary">

            <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>city</th>
                <th>country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         {% for p1 in dataset %}

            <tr>
                <td>{{ p1.name }}</td>
                <td >{{ p1.address }}</td>
                <td >{{ p1.city }}</td>
                <td >{{ p1.country }}</td>
                <td><a href="/pramod1/ pk=p1.id %}">edit</a></td>
                <td><a>Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Im on mobile so icant find a link that easily but the starting point you are looking for is the generic update view

Answer (score 0):

Looking from your code, it looks like a **very raw code** where you are trying to do everything yourself. 
You can try out either of following, to solve this issue:

A. **Class Based views (UpdateView)**:

In Django, **Class Based views** have been introduced which are highly preferred over function based views.

So, the functionality you are coding above can easily be Achieved using **UpdateView** in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview

B. **Model Forms in Django**:

But, If you don't want to change the current view, then you should try Django ModelForms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/

Here is a **sample** use of Model forms: http://www.pythoncentral.io/using-python-django-modelform-first-django-application/

**I would highly recommend you use UpdateView, because it already uses a ModelForm behind the scene**